# Contribution receipt showing no fields

Tags: joomla, email, receipts

We are using CiviCRM 4.7.10 on Joomla 3.6.2.   The contribution receipt isn't showing any field data, except amount and date, though it does show the intro text put into he Contribution form.   This is a contribution form that has an optional donation, but mostly collecting profile data.

My understanding that all fields from this form should display on the receipt - How can we get all the form data to email in the receipt?

[image: sample]

Comment: Why is the template different for online or offline? If I tell it to send the email receipt *as I create the contribution* it uses the offline receipt. But if I go back into the receipt to email an invoice (or create a pdf) it uses the online receipt template? How it this logical? Also the variables in each template are different. How do I display $financial_type and $source in *all* our receipts?

Answer (score 1):

Is this an online or offline receipt. It looks like an offline donation receipt. The information available for each is different.

Comment: That may be part of the issue - its a contribution form with an optional donation.  So I guess Civi would be using the online receipt, since online payment is selected in the form.

Comment: You're right, it's an online receipt (offline would be when you enter it yourself in the backend). Can you revert to the default contribution receipt and run a test donation? If you see the fields in the receipt they may have veen been inadvertently removed when you were customizing.

Comment: It is the default workflow template - and actually had same result with setting it as a contribution and as a membership.   This issue may or may not be related, but still not sure what to do about it:  https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18027

Comment: Can you verify that Civi is retaining the profile data.

Comment: Also, happening for me. All the billing information is being written to the database and appears in the donor's record and CiviContribute GUI.